Cant deploy to heroku, i keep having R10 eror. Rails
So im trying to deploy my rails app basically this is what im using with rails 7.0.6 and ruby 3.1.2:
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hotwired/stimulus": "^3.2.1",
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "^7.3.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^7.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "esbuild": "^0.18.16",
    "flowbite": "^1.8.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.27",
    "stimulus-notification": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --sourcemap --outdir=app/assets/builds --public-path=/assets",
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css --minify"
  }
}

this is my procfile:
release: bundle exec rails db:migrate && bundle exec rails assets:precompile
web: bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0  -p $PORT -e production
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -e production
mqtt_listener: bundle exec rails runner lib/background_mqtt_listener.rb

I added redis for my sidekiq and postgres for the database on the resources tab of heroku.
right now im getting this error:
2024-10-25T15:41:51.671226+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e production`

2024-10-25T15:41:53.866640+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma

2024-10-25T15:41:53.866667+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 7.0.8 application starting in production 

2024-10-25T15:41:53.866667+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options

2024-10-25T15:42:06.000000+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=REDIS addon=redis-trapezoidal-49953 sample#active-connections=1 sample#max-connections=18 sample#connection-percentage-used=0.05556 sample#load-avg-1m=14.79 sample#load-avg-5m=18.55 sample#load-avg-15m=18.76 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0.25 sample#max-iops=3000 sample#iops-percentage-used=0.00008 sample#memory-total=16070672kB sample#memory-free=6740524kB sample#memory-percentage-used=0.58057 sample#memory-cached=5602796kB sample#memory-redis=516528bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0

2024-10-25T15:44:51.914826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 180 seconds of launch

2024-10-25T15:44:51.927279+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2024-10-25T15:44:51.984252+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2024-10-25T15:44:52.005138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

things ive tried to solve the issue but did not change anything:

made sure there is a db connection
made sure the migrations are done
made sure the port variable is set to PORT so that heroku sets it
tried without mqtt and sidekiq
upped the boot time to 180 sec in case it was slow because of that
added peload_app! to puma settings


that is the default set by heroku. if you go over to the resources tab it basically says web bin/rails server -p ${PORT:-5000} -e $RAILS_ENV and there is a button to edit it, but it only lets me turn off the server and save it, not the command
